# in ARMv6, why the value of PC is current instruction plus 8?

Tags: arm, pipeline, program-counter

what if the stages of pipeline is not 3, such as in  ARM1156T2-S (also is ARMv6), it has 9 stages:

```
Fe1 Fe2 De Iss Fe3 Sh ALU Sat WBex
```

the PC is still address of current instruction plus 8?

Answer (score 2):

For compatibility.

```
MOV LR, PC
LDR PC, =myfunc
```

You don't want to break all the old code just because the pipeline was changed.